# Quelle est la signification de "penser sous la ceinture" ?

Tags: traduction

Je suis en train de faire une traduction du français vers l'anglais et il y a la phrase "penser sous la ceinture". Qu'est-ce que ça signifie? Le contexte me fait penser qu'il s'agit d'hommes qui ne pensent pas avec leur tête...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectivement, penser sous la ceinture signifie qu'on ne pense pas "avec sa tête" mais qu'on se laisse guider "par ses hormones" (testostérone). Tout comme "penser avec son coeur" mène à des actes de bonté, "penser sous la ceinture"(pour ne pas citer l'organe qui se trouve juste sous la ceinture) mène à des comportements de "mâle reproducteur".

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre explication!

Comment: Notons que cette expression s'applique autant a des hommes que des femmes